# Ubuntu 17.10 recognizing wrong GPU

Tags: drivers, 17.10, radeon

Ubuntu is recognizing the incorrect GPU and using the wrong driver.
I have Radeon HD 6400M but it thinks its a Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile.

How can I fix this?

Output from lscpi:

```
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760] (rev ff)
```

Checking glxinfo:

```
$ glxinfo | grep evice
Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile  (0x126)
```

When running `dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'`, I get:

```
[    1.155405] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    1.161036] radeon 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    1.161204] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (CAICOS 0x1002:0x6760 0x17AA:0x3976 0x00).
[    1.201196] [drm] GPU not posted. posting now...
[    1.204486] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF (1024M used)
[    1.204487] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000040000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF
[    1.204490] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=1024M, BAR=256M
[    1.204490] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[    1.204576] [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
[    1.204577] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[    1.204582] [drm] Loading CAICOS Microcode
[    1.204646] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[    1.208987] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    1.209049] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
[    1.209596] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[    1.212234] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x0000000000162000).
[    1.212340] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[    1.212342] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff9a125c801c00
[    1.212343] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000040000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff9a125c801c0c
[    1.213095] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x0000000000072118 and cpu addr 0xffffbfe701632118
[    1.213160] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.213161] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.213162] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    1.213202] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    1.213243] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    1.304171] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    1.304172] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    1.310040] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.310041] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.312843] radeon 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    1.444517] [drm:r600_ring_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: ring 0 test failed (scratch(0x8504)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[    1.444523] radeon 0000:01:00.0: disabling GPU acceleration
[    1.446806] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    1.457791] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    1.458122] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20170619 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
[    1.628841] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.628906] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   19.627456] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[   19.628643] radeon 0000:01:00.0: No VRAM object for PCIE GART.
[   19.628668] [drm:evergreen_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* evergreen startup failed on resume
[   25.487343] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[   25.488530] radeon 0000:01:00.0: No VRAM object for PCIE GART.
[   25.488557] [drm:evergreen_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* evergreen startup failed on resume
[   34.542929] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[   34.544161] radeon 0000:01:00.0: No VRAM object for PCIE GART.
[   34.544387] [drm:evergreen_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* evergreen startup failed on resume
[   63.724953] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[   63.726152] radeon 0000:01:00.0: No VRAM object for PCIE GART.
[   63.726211] [drm:evergreen_resume [radeon]] *ERROR* evergreen startup failed on resume
```

Comment: The link does not address my question and at the same time the answers are quite outdated.

Comment: Simply put, there are two GPUs. Ubuntu recognizes both, which is quite right. It is unclear why you think something is wrong with it. If you want to disable the Intel GPU, sometimes there is an option in the BIOS for that.

Comment: @mikewhatever The reason why I say it's wrong is because this is a laptop which specs' states there is only 1 Radeon GPU and 1 Intel integrated CPU.

Comment: @drum most modern Intel CPUs have a GPU component. It's part of the same chip. Your laptop **clearly** has this.